# How do I prove that when the $\arg z=0$, $z= \overline{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How do I prove that when the $\arg z=0$, $z= \overline{z}$?  I visualised it by taking the complex number $z$ with respect to the origin. So that would imply that only the real part of $z$ exists ,which would be equal to the conjugate of $z$. But it's not working for other cases. What should I do next?

Comment: How do you define $\arg$?

Comment: The angle between the complex number vector and the reference vecor,which is the positive x axis here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that if $\alpha$ is the argument of $z$, then there exist $R \geq 0$ in real numbers such that $z=Re^{i\alpha}$. When $\alpha = 0$, $z=R$. Now by definition conjugate of $z$ is $Re^{-i\alpha}$. Plug $\alpha=0$ we get the same result. If your definition is of argument is different than what i've used then proof changed obviously.

Comment: Cool Thanks I got it.I went by the same definition of argument as the one you went by .

Answer (score 1):

Use that if $\arg z = \theta$ if $z$ is of the form $z=r\exp i\theta$. Use the definition of conjugation $\overline{z}=r\exp(-i\theta)$.

Thus
$$z=r\exp(0i) = re^0 = r$$
$$\overline{z}=r\exp(-0i)=re^0=r$$

Comment: Cool Thanks I got it

Comment: @TejeshBhaumik If you found this helpful, up-vote or give the $\color{green}{\checkmark}$. That’s how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: Yeah was gonna do that sorry.

Comment: @TejeshBhaumik I didn’t mean anything aggressive—I just saw that you’re a new user $\ddot\smile$