# How to prove : If a complex number is equal to its own complex conjugate, then it's real.

Tags: complex-numbers

\begin{align}
a+ib&=a-ib \\
a+i2b&=a \\
i2b&=0 \end{align}

To me, this seems weird. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems fine with me. Since $i*2b = 0$, then $2b = 0$. Since the complex part is 0, it is real.

Comment: i2b=0 implies b=0 implies a+ib=a.

Comment: Suggestion: keep going.  If $i2b=0$ then what is the value of $b$?

Comment: why don't you then multiply by $-i/2$?

Comment: It’s not an exact duplicate, but [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2588374/347062) is relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Let $z=a+bi$ be a complex number, where $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

Then, it's complex conjugate is : $\bar{z}=a-bi$.

If $z=\bar{z}$ then :

$$a+bi = a-bi \Leftrightarrow 2bi = 0 \Rightarrow bi = 0$$

Obviously, the imaginary unit $i$ is $\neq 0$, so it must be $b=0$.

But note that $b$ is the imaginary part of the complex number $z$ and more specifically :

$$b = \Im\{z\} = 0$$

Since the imaginary part is zero, this means that $z$ is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically done. If $2bi = 0$, then $b=0$. Your number is of the form $a+bi$, so if $b=0$, the number is real (no imaginary part).

Answer (score 0):

$$
a+bi=a-bi\implies bi=-bi\implies i(bi)=-i(bi)\implies -b=b
$$
either $b$ is zero or $1=-1$ which is silly. So $b=0$.

You may also multiply 
$$
2bi=0
$$
on both sides by $\frac{-i}{2}$ to conclude $b=0$.